# Getting data from the session[] Python, Flask

Tags: python, html, session, flask

I'm trying to make simple cart system to the online shop using Python and framework - Flask.
I'm getting data from form in products.html then writing it into the session. I have a problem with getting this data and returning it to the cart.html - I'm get just clear page instead of names of the products i added to the cart.

products.html

```
    {% for el in products %}
        <p>Name {{ el.product_name }}</p>
        <p>Description {{ el.product_description }}</p>
        <p>Image </p> <img width="200" height="200" src="data:;base64,{{ el.product_img }}">
        <p>Cost: {{ el.product_cost }} тенге.</p>

        <form method="post" action="/cart">
            <input type="hidden" name="cart_prod_name" value="{{ el.product_name }}">
            <input type="submit" value="Add to cart">
        </form>
    {% endfor %}
```

Python function `cart()`:

```
@app.route('/cart', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def cart():
    if 'cart' not in session:
        session['cart'] = []

    if request.method == 'POST':
        cart_prod_name = request.form['cart_prod_name']
        session['cart'] += cart_prod_name
        return redirect('/cart')

    if request.method == 'GET':
        cart_products = session['cart']
        return render_template('cart.html', cart_products=cart_products)
```

cart.html:

```
{% for cart_product in cart_products %}
    <p>{{ cart_product.order_prod_name }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sloved that problem. Exactly I needed to iterate `cart_product` in `cart_roducts` and output `cart_product` and don't call it to output `order_prod_name`.

Fixed `cart.html`:

```
{% for cart_product in cart_products %}
    <p>{{ cart_product }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

From `flask.session` docs:

> Be advised that modifications on mutable structures are not picked up
> automatically, in that situation you have to explicitly set the
> attribute to True yourself.

your carts holder object is a mutable structure == list so you have to set after changes

```
session.modified = True
```

Comment: I tried that and get same result -  just clear page

Comment: Ok can you debug what is in form while POST `print(request.form['cart_prod_name'])`? also don't use list += str, there is a method list.append(str)

Comment: also you can get session object in template directly. Add this to your template  `{{session['cart']|pprint}}`

Comment: `request.from['cart_prod_name']` gives me `product_name`, e.g I get `product1`. Also I debugged writing this name to session and it's works, I can write `product1` in the `session['cart']`. I only need get this name from there and put it into html template

Comment: I also tried to see element code of me cart.html page and I have `<p>` tags where should be names of products from `session['cart']`